# Error assert(): assert(sizeof($failures) == 1) failed stops Codeception Test

Tags: codeception

At some point, while adding assertions for my test, I got the following error message during a test run which stops the execution of the test

```
Testing started at 14:28 ...
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:/Users/georg/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-codeception.php run --report -o "reporters: report: PhpStorm_Codeception_ReportPrinter" --no-interaction -c C:/Users/georg/Documents/CMS_Automation_Tests/codeception.yml "tests\regression\features\ArticleTests.feature:Create a new article and fill out all available fields"
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.7
Powered by PHPUnit 9.3.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 
In ErrorHandler.php line 83:
assert(): assert(sizeof($failures) == 1) failed
run [-o|--override OVERRIDE] [-e|--ext EXT] [--report] [--html [HTML]] [--xml [XML]] [--phpunit-xml [PHPUNIT-XML]] [--tap [TAP]] [--json [JSON]] [--colors] [--no-colors] [--silent] [--steps] [-d|--debug] [--bootstrap [BOOTSTRAP]] [--no-redirect] [--coverage [COVERAGE]] [--coverage-html [COVERAGE-HTML]] [--coverage-xml [COVERAGE-XML]] [--coverage-text [COVERAGE-TEXT]] [--coverage-crap4j [COVERAGE-CRAP4J]] [--coverage-phpunit [COVERAGE-PHPUNIT]] [--no-exit] [-g|--group GROUP] [-s|--skip SKIP] [-x|--skip-group SKIP-GROUP] [--env ENV] [-f|--fail-fast] [--no-rebuild] [--seed SEED] [--no-artifacts] [--] [<suite> [<test>]]
```

I didn't find any information about this error. It doesn't seem to be related to any specific error in my code.

[image]

My composer.json is below:

```json
{
    "name": "cms/automation",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
        "php-webdriver/webdriver": "^1.8@dev",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-mb$ vendor/bin/behat -V\nstring": "*",
        "facebook/webdriver": "1.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.5",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.1",
        "codeception/base": "^2.4",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.1",
        "behat/behat": "^3.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it possible that you reformat the error you are getting to improve its readability? You could also try to describe the attached image so people are more inclined to answer. It might also be interesting which code you executed that results in this error.

Comment: That error originates from PhpStorm plugin. As far as I know, it is closed source.

Comment: Here is the code of plugin, that I extracted 3 years ago https://gist.github.com/Naktibalda/16395382be61a27e69357cf3d0cf1e7d#file-codeception-php-L356
The same issue was raised in YouTrack, but there was no response from JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35880

Comment: Which would be the plugin causing the issue? I've tried disabling multiple plugins, I've updated to the latest PHP Storm version, I've updated multiple dependencies.

Comment: I would appreciate a workaround for the error since it's currently blocking any further development.

Comment: If it blocks development, run Codeception in console.

Comment: @Naktibalda running the test through the terminal fails the test as well. I am unable to move forward, is it possible to resolve this error? What exactly is causing this In ErrorHandler.php line 83:
                                                   
  assert(): assert(sizeof($failures) == 1) failed

Comment: It fails, because more than 1 error happened in failed test.
I don't use PhpStorm Plugin.  If you need help with debugging test errors in console, ask for help in Codeception Slack https://join.slack.com/t/codeception/shared_invite/zt-41cdilu9-FzZaDkz~QQxuX_c0oUC__w

Comment: Thanks. However, I really don't understand which is the plugin you're talking about. Also, there aren't any errors as per the report of the executed steps.

Comment: I had a similar error. After I fixed some syntax problem in one of the not really related components, the error `assert(sizeof($failures) == 1) failed` was gone.